# subsection font size with beamer theme Warsaw

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fontsize

I am trying to change the font size of `subsection` bar of a `beamer` presentation using `Warsaw`.
I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28816/subsection-size-in-header-doesnt-change-header-height) which is doing exactly the same for the `Berlin`. I tried that in my presentation with `Warsaw` and getting error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeDarmsta
dt.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesm
oothbars.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.32 }
```

Not much insight to me.
I am putting my minimal code (using Berlin), to show what I want to achieve with Warsaw. I just want to have such larger `subsection` `headerbar` using Warsaw

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Berlin} \setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamerfont*{section in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont*{subsection in head/foot}{size=\large}

\newlength\SubHt
\settoheight\SubHt{\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}S}
\newlength\SubDh
\settodepth\SubDh{\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}g}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.5\SubHt,dp=1.5\SubDh,%defaults: ht=2.5ex,  dp=1.125ex
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{sec1}
  \subsection{sss}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \lipsum
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28816/subsection-size-in-header-doesnt-change-header-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Warsaw` uses the `shadow` outer theme, which is in turn based on `split`; whereas `Berlin` uses the `miniframes` outer theme.

To get what you want, you just have to look into your local `texmf` tree,

> TEXMF/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/outer/

find the `beamerouterthemesplit.sty` file, copy the definition for `headline`. Then make the appropriate changes to the height and depth.

## Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Warsaw} \setbeamercovered{transparent}}
% \usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamerfont*{section in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont*{subsection in head/foot}{size=\large}

\newlength\SubHt
\settoheight\SubHt{\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}S}
\newlength\SubDh
\settodepth\SubDh{\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}g}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=1.5\SubHt,dp=1.5\SubDh]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=1.5\SubHt,dp=1.5\SubDh]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{sec1}
  \subsection{sss}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the beamerfont `headline`:

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\large}

\begin{document}
  \section{sec1}
  \subsection{sss}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Wow that's elegant! This is indeed the way to go. Works as expected for `Darmstadt`.