# How to increase the size of navigation circles?

Tags: beamer, navigation

As per [Subsection size in header doesn't change header height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28816/subsection-size-in-header-doesnt-change-header-height/151769#151769), it is very easy to increase the size of the Section/Subsection font in Beamer using `\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\huge}`. However, in e.g. `Darmsdadt` theme this has no effect on the navigation circles (the tiny circles right below the Section title).

How can I increase the size of the navigation circles?

**Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt} 
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\huge}

\begin{document}
  \section{Section 1}
  \subsection{Subsection 1}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The value for the size of the circles is hard coded to 0.05cm (in the below example changed to 0.15cm). If you want to change it, you have to redefine the templates. For boxes things seem easier, as their size is `\beamer@boxsize`.

But instead of digging through the definitions of beamer, another approach to get bigger font and navigation circles would be to decrease the page size.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt} 
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\huge}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame}{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.15cm}{0.15cm}}{0.15cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.15cm}{0.15cm}}{0.15cm}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{0.1cm}{0.1cm}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.15cm}{0.15cm}}{0.15cm}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamersize{mini frame size=0.4cm, mini frame offset=0.3cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{Section 1}
  \subsection{Subsection 1}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame}
        Content
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]