# Changing default font size in Frankfurt Beamer slides without impacting the spacing on the navigation bar

Tags: beamer, fontsize, navigation, rmarkdown

I am trying to reduce the standard font size in a Beamer presentation, created in Rmarkdown, using the Frankfurt theme.

When I set `fontsize: 10pt` (as desired) in the YAML it impacts the spacing in the navigation bar... see below for a screenshot of the last slide.

I have tried messing around with `\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\large}` as in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151769/14826), but I am not to sure where to put the command in the .Rmd file - everywhere i have tried so far has no impact.

Some code to replicate the crappy spacing...

```
---
title: "Untitled"
fontsize: 10pt
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Frankfurt"
    slide_level: 3
---

# Section 1

## .

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

### Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

... and a screenshot of the navigation bar in a standard slide

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip0.5ex}{}` to the header